# Check tag & get the value inside tag using PHP

Tags: php, text

I've been confused. So here's my problem, I have a text like this :

```
<ORGANIZATION>Head of Pekalongan Regency</ORGANIZATION>, Dra. Hj.. Siti Qomariyah , MA and her staff were greeted by <ORGANIZATION>Rector of IPB</ORGANIZATION> Prof. Dr. Ir. H. Herry Suhardiyanto , M.Sc. and <ORGANIZATION>officials of IPB</ORGANIZATION> in the guest room.
```

I'm try to get the value inside `<ORGANIZATION>` tag using my code :

```
function get_text_between_tags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches[1]))
        return $matches[1];
}
```

But this code only retrieve one value from the last tag (`officials of IPB`) when there are 3 tags `<ORGANIZATION>`.

Now, I don't have idea to modify this code to get all value inside tag without duplication. So please help, thanks in advance. :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @MatthewGraves I don't get it that article (my english bad). Is there any hope?

Comment: why I got the vote down :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preg_match` will only return the first match, and your current code will fail if:

- The tag is not uppercased in the same way
- The tag's contents are on more than one line
- There are more than one of the tag on the same line.

Instead, try this:

```
function get_text_between_tags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/is";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches[1]))
        return $matches[1];
    return array();
}
```

This is acceptable use of regexes for parsing, because it is a clearly-defined case. Note however that it will fail if, for whatever reason, there is a `>` inside an attribute value of the tag.

If you prefer to avoid [the wrath of the pony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), try this:

```
function get_text_between_tags($string, $tagname) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($string);
    $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tagname);
    $out = array();
    $length = $tags->length;
    for( $i=0; $i<$length; $i++) $out[] = $tags->item($i)->nodeValue;
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: I've tried, but still don't work. It's return an empty array. :)

Comment: I'm sorry before, I've tried the second code. The first code is work. Thanks master. :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the `strip_tags()` function?

```
<?php

    $s = "<ORGANIZATION>Head of Pekalongan Regency</ORGANIZATION>, Dra. Hj.. Siti Qomariyah , MA and her staff were greeted by <ORGANIZATION>Rector of IPB</ORGANIZATION> Prof. Dr. Ir. H. Herry Suhardiyanto , M.Sc. and <ORGANIZATION>officials of IPB</ORGANIZATION> in the guest room.";

    $r = strip_tags($s);

    var_dump($r);

?>
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/5zljPc8C)